# .htaccess: sanitize a query string

Tags: .htaccess

So I have some particular variables that mess up the content management system I'm using.
   While I debug the code, I'd like to redirect requests with these particular variables back to the index page, but without any query string.

Here's my rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option\=com\_aicontactsafe\&sTask\=captcha
RewriteRule (.*) "/index.php" [R=301, L]
```

At this point it is simply writing the file path to index.php after the HTTP_HOST.
This gives a 403, but is not quite what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to `/index.php?` instead of just `/index.php`. Normally mod_rewrite doesn't touch the query string, unless you give it a new query string to replace the old one with.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Though in order to make it work right I had to ditch the redirect and add a proxy flag.
The rule ended up looking like:
`RewriteRule (.*) "/index.php?" [P, L]`

Comment: Ah, silly me, I completely missed the fact that you had an external redirect in there. Anyway, glad it worked.